# How to change Text Color of CheckBoxPreference's Title in android?

Tags: java, android, customization, checkboxpreference

I want to do this: when the CheckBoxPreference is unchecked, the text color of the CheckBoxPreference's title become gray and if checked, the title's text color reverts to original color (depends on the theme).

What I did until now: I created a new class extending from `CheckBoxPreference`.

```
public class CustomCheckBoxPreference extends CheckBoxPreference{

    TextView txtTitle;
    int originalTextColor;

    public CustomCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {

        txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        originalTextColor = txtTitle.getCurrentTextColor();

        setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (isChecked()) {
                    txtTitle.setTextColor(originalTextColor);  //it doesn't work
                }
                else {
                    txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);  //it doesn't work
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        super.onBindView(view);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, the `txtTitle.setTextColor(..)` apparently didn't work, the text color didn't change at all. I also have confirmed with the debugger that the `onPreferenceClick` method was called.

Comment: you are using a check isChecked() but where is it defined? instead of using just icChecked() you need to use ((CheckBoxPreference)preference).isChecked() for checking purpose

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela: I extended from the CheckBoxPreference class, that's where it is come from.

Answer (score 0):

Even I did the same and didn't work for me, I too don't know the reason.

But it will work, if you remove `onPreferenceClickListener()` and use only if else.

```
protected void onBindView(View view) {

    txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    originalTextColor = txtTitle.getCurrentTextColor();


            if (isChecked()) {
                txtTitle.setTextColor(originalTextColor); 
            }
            else {
                txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY); 
            }
            return true;

    super.onBindView(view);

}
```